# Intermittent ColdFusion 404 Error Page, Sometimes it shows Connect Reset / Interrupted and sometimes it shows the error page

Tags: iis, coldfusion, windows-server-2008, intermittent, connection-reset

I have a strange issue with 404 pages loaded on our new site.  We just moved our site from a ColdFusion 8 single instance setup to a ColdFusion 10 setup with 3 instances of ColdFusion running.  This is running on IIS 7.5 with Windows Server 2008 R2.  The IIS site has it's 404 error set to load /404.cfm which was a setting copied from the previous server setup.

The issue is that when you load a page that does not exist, some of the time the 404 page loads and sometimes you just get a connection reset error.  For example, if you go to http://www.weblisters.com/doesnotexist and refresh repeatedly, you will see many times the connection is reset and some other times it will display the 'Sorry, Page Not Found' template.

I thought that this might be due to the multiple instances so I turned off 2 of the 3 instances so only 1 would be running and it did not affect the behavior.

Does anyone else have any ideas to what could cause this intermittent behavior?

EDIT:  Here is a screen cast of what is happening on my end.  http://screencast.com/t/0gD0lwZiRI

Comment: Nope - That page (no matter how much I refresh) isn't showing a connection reset page. Is that the page you're having issues with? Or is it an example?

Comment: It is any non-existent URL link, including that one.  I had to refresh almost 20 times just to get the actual page to load, so it may take a few times.  If we set the IIS custom error page to do a 302 redirect it works every time (we do not want to use the 302 redirect), but when it is set to Execute a URL on this site, it loads very infrequently.  Here is a screen capture of what is happening on my end.  http://screencast.com/t/0gD0lwZiRI

Comment: I tried several times and only got the 404

Comment: Tomcat redirects and IIS 7.5 routing are in conflict. I have heard Coldfusion has an update to fix this. This link may help http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-10-update-1-10-0-1-released otherwise a third party ISAPI library may help.

Comment: @Travis Thanks for trying. How often I get the connection reset varies from location to location (so it seems).

Comment: @FrankTudor That at least gives me a direction to look into, although we are currently on ColdFusion Update 5.  There is an update 6 out there that I will install, but the link you provided is for Update 1.

Comment: At our firm we have complicated redirects and simple ones as well.  Coldfusion 9 on IIS 7.5 is solid with our web config redirectors.  Coldfusion 10 (moved away from the JVM, to Tomcat, which is fine), but as soon as we tried testing on the latest and greatest our ISAPI stuff was getting intercepted by Tomcat.  To make a long story short we are staying with version 9 until we can figure out another way to keep visitors on the right paths.

Comment: Interestingly, even when the browser is saying "connection reset", the request is actually completing "fine", the correct mark-up is there and a status 200 OK is being returned. It's just the mark-up isn't being rendered. So it's not like the request is not running. I'd use an HTTP sniffer to compare a response that renders, and one that doesn't to see what the difference is. Temporarily remove all the CF logic from the process, just replacing it with static mark-up. Indeed perhaps direct 404s to 404.html so as to bypass CF completely. See what that gives you.

Comment: Also worthy of note, your 404 page is returning a "200 OK" HTTP status code. It should be returning a 404!

Comment: Also: I only get the correct 404 page less than 1% of the time.

Comment: @billvsd, can you please contact me offline. My email address is in my profile. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem today.  I found the comments by Charlie Arehart on this page to be most helpful:  http://forums.adobe.com/message/4784188

Basically: after updating CF10, make sure to run the Web Connector as admin.

Comment: Thanks, Marcus. I'll add also that these problems can have lots of reasons and solutions. And FWIW, some who have had such connection reset problems with IIS-based CF 404 handlers, have found their solution was to implement some IIS rewrite rules, as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694932/coldfusion-10-iis-non-existant-urls-that-are-cfm-files-retrieving-original-u. Just offering that in case it may help someone reading this thread here.