# ColdFusion 10 + IIS: Non-existant URLs that are CFM files. Retrieving original URL after executing 404 page

Tags: tomcat, iis, coldfusion

We have a server setup as follows:

- Windows 2012 R2
- Coldfusion 10, Enterprise
- IIS, configure with custom 404 page (execute on server)

The custom 404 page (a CFM file) handles missing URLs and checks them against custom URLs in the database. If it finds a match, it will display the relevant data. The problem occurs when the custom URL maps to a non-existant CFM file; for example.

/home/map.cfm (not a real file or directory)

Now, when a user requests this URL, the server sees that it is a CFM file and correctly passes it to ColdFusion (via the ISAPI redirect). Tomcat sees that this file does not actually exist, and returns a 404. IIS sees this 404 message and executes the custom error page (/errors/404.cfm).

The resulting CGI variables do not infact allow us to retrieve the original URL (to map it to a virtual URL in the database), usually provided as part of the CGI.QUERY_STRING variable. Instead, the QUERY_STRING variable contains the path to the 'isapi_rewrite.dll' file, in the 'jakarta' directory.

Is there any way to retain the originally requested URL (of a CFM file), after Tomcat has returned a 404 error for said page?

**Solution, put together by myself, inspired by Thomas Gorgolione**

As suspected, the issue invariably came down to the request being forwarded to the ISAPI_REDIRECT module, even if the file in question did not exist.

As Thomas suggested, an elegant solution is to utilize rewrites to check that the file / directory actually exists, before passing it through to the ISAPI_REDIRECT module.

While the software Thomas suggested would of done the trick, I was unable to get it to install on a 64bit Windows 2012 R2 machine. I've managed however to fall back to utilize the URL Rewrite module included with IIS8 (and possibly earlier versions).

See my web.config entry below that provides a solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        </httpErrors>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="404 HTTP">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="CFFileServlet/(.*)" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="0" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/404.cfm?404;http://{HTTP_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="404 HTTPS">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="CFFileServlet/(.*)" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="1" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/404.cfm?404;https://{HTTP_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The above configuration file takes into account both HTTP and HTTPS requests. It will also take into account the the CFFileServlet directory, which ColdFusion uses to host temporary images and assets. If the URL starts with this directory, it will be passed on as a normal request.

Thanks for your input everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE: Question above includes a solution as well.**

I think this is an error with the Coldfusion Connector.  I would post a bug report to Adobe (https://bugbase.adobe.com/).  I do have a workaround though.  I have the same issue, but I use IIRF (Ionic IIS Redirector - http://iirf.codeplex.com/), and I found a way to use that to avoid the bug for now:

1. Remove any previous 404 file configuration in IIS/Coldfusion
2. Install IIRF normally, according to it's install instructions.
3. In the IirfGlobal.ini file (normally located in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\IIRF), add the following line:

   ```
   RewriteFilterPriority HIGH
   ```

   This will allow IIRF to handle 404 requests before it even hits ColdFusion/Tomcat.
4. In the site-specific Iirf.ini (usually you create one in the root folder of your web files -- see the IIRF docs for details), add the following rules:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_TRANSLATED} !-f
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_TRANSLATED} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ page_to_redirect_to.cfm?404;$1 [L]
   ```

   That will redirect all files/directories that don't exist to page_to_redirect_to.cfm, and add the 404 query string like normal.
5. **EDIT: Added a following step:** Go into the IIS Manager and select either the server or the Web Site that was configured to use IIRF, then go into the ISAPI Filters section.  Click on "View Ordered List", then move the IIRF filter up to the top.

**EDIT 2:** Just posted a bug to Adobe.  See https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3630245

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice, thanks Thomas - I'll give that a go on our development server now.

Comment: This looks like a workable solution, however unfortunately IIRF fails to install on our server, providing a completely unhelpful error code in the MSIEXEC log file. We may be able to use another rewrite module such as Helicon to achieve the same goal.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, because you put me on to the correct path to fixing this issue. In the end, I have actually used the URL Rewrite module included with IIS 8 to the same effect. I've included the web.config entry in my question, as reference for others. Thank you very much.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I'll edit the question (noticed an additional step I needed to put in), and note your solution at the top.

Comment: Yeah any URL Rewrite module should do it, as long as it runs before ColdFusion

Comment: Thanks for the bug report as well, I'll try and place a vote on that now.

Comment: **That will redirect all files/directories that don't exist to page_to_redirect_to.cfm**. But it is not redirecting to that page it is rewriting. Please i need your help here.

Answer (score 2):

Let me preface my answer by stating that I am still running ColdFusion 9 so I don't have first-hand experience with the 404 handling in ColdFusion 10 with Tomcat. Obviously I will need to upgrade to version 10 so I am trying to familiarize myself with it's nuances (like handling 404's). So I did some searching.

As you stated in your question, with ColdFusion 9 and IIS the originally requested file is normally contained with the `CGI.QUERY_STRING` variable prepended with "404;".  With ColdFusion 10 and Tomcat it appears as though some other `CGI` variables contain the originally requested file and it depends on your setup which variable that is.

I found this blog post by Raymond Camden - [Reminder--there-is-more-to-the-CGI-scope-than-what-the-dump-shows](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/9/3/Reminder--there-is-more-to-the-CGI-scope-than-what-the-dump-shows). While that contains good info in itself I also found within the comments by [Jules Gravinese](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/9/3/Reminder--there-is-more-to-the-CGI-scope-than-what-the-dump-shows#cFDA04558-0D88-72AE-FA6C2CD0F50534B1) the following:

When using **IIS7** the variable is `CGI.HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL`

When using **ISAPI_rewrite** the variable is `CGI.HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL`

When using **APACHE** the variable is `CGI.REDIRECT_URL`

I also found some other articles referencing a `CGI.REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` variable which I believe is also included when using **APACHE**.

---

Found another article from Adobe regarding the CGI variables and how they are used with ColdFusion (and how/why it is not a complete list): [CGI environment (CGI Scope) variables](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/CGI+environment+%28CGI+Scope%29+variables).

---

**NOTE:**  I also found this bug [ColdFusion 10.0 - Bug 3488063: IIS 404 custom error handler URLs that are .cfm files do not consistently return entire document](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3488063) which has been closed but several recent comments suggest that it is still an issue. So be aware of that.

Comment: Thanks for your input - I did not know about the 'hidden' CGI fields. Unfortunately, none of these fields were present during the request.

Also, thanks for your subnote regarding the incomplete document. We have already done battle with this bug, and come out on top (forced a 'Connection: Close' header, and disabled Dynamic Compression).

Comment: It is amazing how un-documented this functionality is. Everything I am finding points to the CGI variables I mentioned. Not sure why you are not seeing them? Unfortunately I do not have a CF10 installation to work with. Hopefully someone else will chime in.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Application.cfc OnMissingTemplate method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/AppEvents_07.html) to handle a missing template page.

In Application.cfc add this

```
<cffunction name="onMissingTemplate">
    <cfargument name="targetPage" type="string" required=true/>

    <!--- No standard error handling here so we need to try/catch --->
    <cftry>
        <!--- Can't do a redirect so we'll do an "include" --->
        <cfset missingPage=Arguments.targetPage>
        <cfinclude template="/errors/404.cfm">

        <cfcatch>
          <!--- Let the standard missing file (404) process occur --->
            <cfreturn false />
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cffunction>
```

In /errors/404.cfm add this near the top

```
<cfparam name="missingPage" type="string" default="">
<cfif missingPage eq "">
  <!--- Include CGI variable and process as fitting for your purposes --->
  <cfset missingPage=CGI.QUERY_STRING>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is currently not an option, and to be honest we have had a great deal of bad experience utilizing Application.cfc error settings with IIS.

Comment: I understand.  Were those related to doing a cflocation?  It's very specific about what you can and cannot call.

Comment: @Seidr can you explain more on your solution? I'm also having this issue (re: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17956552/159710)

Comment: @ShawnE A CFLocation was not performed, this request was direct to the non-existent CFM file.

Comment: @RHPT No solution as of yet has been found. Strangely though, the request succeeds if we change the 'virtual' path to a subfolder (in this case /home/map) and include index.cfm (the default document) in the path (resulting in /home/map/index.cfm). This hits the 404 handler with the correct QUERY_STRING when visiting /home/map, where as the direct visit to /home/map.cfm does not. Very odd.